# Simple promise with forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, q

I am trying to use a Promise to wait for an async forEach:

```
var forEachMatch = function(matches) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    matches.forEach(function(match) {
        var messages = Message.find({'matchid': match._id}, function(err,messages) {
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log(match._id);
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Used here:

```
forEachMatch(matches, function() {
    console.log("DONE");
    res.status(200).json({
        bob,
        matches: matches,
    });
});
```

My console output is the following: all `match._id` are printed but `DONE` never.

Any idea to fix it? I begin with node and promises so I certainly forget something but I do not see what.

Thank you for any answer.

## EDIT

The final solution, thanks to Alexander Mac:

```
var forEachMatch = function(matches) {
  var promises = matches.map(match => {
    return Message
    .find({'matchid': match._id})
    .populate({
      path: 'fromUser toUser',
      select: 'id firstname'
    })
    .then(messages => [match, messages])
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error in forEachMatch");
      return [match, null];
    });
  });
  return Q.all(promises);
}

forEachMatch(matches)
  .then(messagesByMatch => {
    res.status(200).json({
      user,
      messagesByMatch: messagesByMatch
    });
  });
```

Comment: Your forEachMatch method only take one argument so your callback with DONE is never called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case match better to use `Q.all`, which accepts array of promises or values:

```
var forEachMatch = function(matches) {
  var promises = matches.map(match => {
    return Message
      .find({'matchid': match._id})
      .then(messages => [match, messages]);
  });
  return Q.all(promises);
}

forEachMatch(matches)
  .then(results => {
    console.log("DONE", results);
    res.status(200).json({
      bob,
      matches: matches,
  });
});
```

https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall

Comment: Is-it possible with this solution to return data at then end of .map function? I work on a variable on each iteration of `matches.map` and want to return it at the end.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but what do you want return? all `match._id`?

Comment: Please see my edit on your answer, I want to handle error and return the result.

Comment: Please add it as a comment.

Comment: `var forEachMatch = function(matches) {
  var result = [];
  var promises = matches.map(match => Message.find({'matchid': match._id}, function(error, messages) {
    if(error)
        // return error
    else {
        result.push([match,messages]);
    }));
  return Q.all(promises);
}`

Comment: Changed example, now `results` contains all `matches` and `messages`.

Comment: Yes that's it! Last point, how to manage error in Message.find?

Comment: Add `catch` handler after `.then(messages => [match, messages]);` => `.catch(err => { console.log('Error'); return [match, null]; })`.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a deferred promise and that promise doesn't get resolved or rejected . Try the following:

```
var forEachMatch = function(matches) {
var deferred = Q.defer();
matches.forEach(function(match) {
    var messages = Message.find({'matchid': match._id}, function(err,messages) {
        if(err)
            deferred.reject(err);
        else
            deferred.resolve(match._id);
    });
});
return deferred.promise;
```

};

the caller will then become

```
    forEachMatch(matches).then(id=>{

     console.log("done succesffuly found");

   }).catch(err=>{
         console.log("not found error",err);
   }).done(()=>{
         console.log("done")
   });
```

Comment: What is the difference between `.then` and `.done` closures? Is `.then` closure called at each iteration of `matches.forEach`?

Answer (score 0):

You never called the `promise.reject` or `promise.reject` methods. Also, a promise is made for asynchronous operations, which forEach isn't.

Here is a dirty fix:

```
 var forEachMatch = function(matches) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  // make the foreach asynchronous
  setTimeout(function() {
    matches.forEach(function(match) {
      // do stuff
    });
    // notify end
    deferred.resolve();
  }, 0);

  return deferred.promise;
};

// use .then
forEachMatch(matches).then(function() {
  console.log("DONE");
});
```

Comment: So what is the best way to wait for the end of my forEach before doing something else like sending the request result?